# How to replace the first parameter name in query string using .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

I need to change the name of the first parameter in the query string from **p** (lower case) to **P** (upper case). It is the first parameter in the query string.

For example, I need to change the url from:

```
http://www.example.com/shop/?p=product_name
```

to

```
http://www.example.com/shop/?P=product_name
```

The framework is wordpress.

The .htaccess code:

```html
    # BEGIN WordPress
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=([^&])$
        RewriteRule ^securestore/?$ $0?P=%1 [L,NC,R=302]
        RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
        RedirectMatch 301 ^(.*)/EcoSupp$ $1
    </IfModule>
```

Comment: There are about 62392363492 examples shown for this alone here on SO.  What in all those examples did not work for you? (you _did_ search for the answer before posting a question, didn't you?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^securestore/?$ $0?P=%1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you anubhava  for your prompt response. I tried your solution but it didn't work. I'm working in a wordpress environment.
Another question: Why did you use 302 and not 301?

Here is the code in the htacess:
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RedirectMatch 301 ^(.*)/EcoSupp$ $1
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=([^&])$
RewriteRule ^shop/?$ $0?P=%1 [L,NC,R=302]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Comment: anubhava - I changed the htacess file and open a new browser but it didn't work. I've modified my question with the content of the htaccess file.
Thank you, Sam

Comment: http://www.ecosupp.tempurl.co.il/securestore/?p=product_name

This is the development site. The site has a plugin coming soon so an external user will not be able to access the page. only the admin that logged into the wordpress system.
Thank you, Sam

Comment: Oops I had a typo. Fixed it in the answer, try my updated rule now.

Comment: It worked wonderfully!!! Thank you anubhava. I just had to remove the extra space after the "^". Should be  ^securestore/?$ $0?P=%1 [L,NC,R=302] instead of  ^ securestore/?$ $0?P=%1 [L,NC,R=302]. Thank you again.