# How to replace the first parameter in a query string?

Tags: regex, wordpress, .htaccess

I'm trying to change this query "https://myurl.com/puff/?search_keyword=xyz" into this one "https://myurl.com/puff/?s=xyz".

I saw an answer similar to this, but I haven't used regular expressions before and had issues customizing it to what I need. I'm using WordPress and editing the .htaccess file to achieve this.

I looked into [How to replace the first parameter name in query string using .htaccess?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29429320/how-to-replace-the-first-parameter-name-in-query-string-using-htaccess) and tried to use that to customize my own .htaccess but had issues implementing it on my own.

This is what my current .htaccess file looks like:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /puffadvisor/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /puffadvisor/index.php [L]x
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

All help is greatly appreciated :) thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You need a condition based on `%QUERY_STRING` and then references to the capture groups prefixed by `%`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*(?:^|&))seach_keyword((?:$|=|&).*)
RewriteRule /puff /puff?%1s%2
```

This `{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/.htaccess` replaces the parameter name `search_keyword` with `s` on `/puff` location, no matter at which position the parameter occurs.

You might want to rewrite all pathes

```
RewriteRule .* $0?%1s%2
```

Comment: I appended it to the bottom, right before </IfModule>, it didn't seem to do anything. Do I have to place the code somewhere else?

Comment: @RomaanNaeem Your `RewriteBase` might make trouble. It is only useful on location aliases. Start testing with a clean .htaccess on the root.